# First time setting up Ghost blog on Amazon Ec2 various noob questions

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2, ghost-blog

Ok so here's some quick info about my setup:

-`Amazon Ec2` instance with an elastic IP associated to it
- Latest versions of node and `Ghost`
- Using `Windows 8` with `Putty`
- Domain from `Namecheap`

So I installed ghost and node on my Amazon EC2 instance using this guide: http://www.bybigs.com/setup-ghost-on-amazon-web-services/

Everything went well(I think). Just at the part where I have to change the IP addresses I'm not sure I did everything correctly. Do I have to change every IP address I see? I found a lot of `127.0.0.1` adresses that I went ahead and changed to my private IP from AWS. I also changed the link to my domain.
The problem I've run into now is the last step: So, type `npm install forever -g` and once that's done you can start the server by typing `NODE_ENV=production forever start index.js`, and you can close the `SSH` window.

I seem to get quite a few error messages when I type in `npm install forever -g` so I don't even move on. But when I type in `npm start` everything seems to be ok.

Now my other problem is with my domain. I bought it on `namecheap` and read online I need to change the `A record` to point to my elastic IP. I've done that for the `A www` and `@ record`. Is there anything else I need to do?

When I go on my domain it shows up as ***this page cannot be displayed***. So something must have gone wrong along the way. Can anybody help a noob out?

Comment: You should focus on one problem at a time when you ask questions here and get it to its simplest form. You can check if your domain name is pointing to the correct location by pinging from your own computer. Some questions I would ask you are: Is anything logging on the server when you try to request a page? Does the terminal output anything at all when it's running? Can you access it via localhost in the browser on the EC2 machine?

Comment: Written a detailed guide for Windows including PuTTY and npm forever here: http://netsca.pe/how-setup-ghost-amazon-ec2/ Let me know if it helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you post the output when you run `npm install forever -g`?

You only have to change the IP address in the production section.

Is there a particular reason you want to use Forever?  If the only reason is because of the tutorial you linked to checkout out my [post](http://www.allaboutghost.com/keep-ghost-running-with-pm2/) on running Ghost with pm2.

Lastly, if you do not want to do the setup to get Ghost running on an EC2 instance you can use our [AWS AMI](http://www.howtoinstallghost.com/how-to-setup-an-amazon-ec2-instance-to-host-ghost-for-free/).  The AMI has everything pre installed and running so you just have to launch it.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I ended up figuring it all out by trial and error.